# Trying to run HTTP POST request on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am currently having problems with Jenkins, I have this configuration in my job:

[image]

But when I execute the job, get the following output:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project1.0
HttpMethod: POST
URL: mypagehome.php
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: page.php
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
atjenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.authAndRequest(HttpRequestExecution.java:215)
at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:187)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:190)
at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:61)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequest.perform(HttpRequest.java:304)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Build step 'HTTP Request' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am new at Jenkins, and until today I knew that one can make http requests with it, do you have any idea what could I be doing wrong?
Thanks!!

**EDIT:**  I see, it meant the http protocol, so I added it, now I'm getting this error: Treating UnknownHostException(mypage.php: Name or service not known) as 404 Not Found Sorry for being such a noob at this, can you please help me out

Comment: I wouldn't actually close this issue because of a typo. It's more that the concept of a protocol and other parts of the URL might not be known to @Yeinor.

Comment: I've added the EDIT you posted as another answer (which is likely to be deleted soon). What did you add now? You've set `http://mypage.php` now? Well.. please read about [what a URL is on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). I told you there should be e.g. `localhost` as host name. `mypage.php` as a file on some host. But I don't know, where you have that and what your intention is. I'm not sure, what you're doing and if it actually would do what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

It says

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: page.php

So change `mypage.php` (that differs in the error and your screen shot?) to a valid URL, e.g. `http://localhost/mypage.php` (or wherever this endpoint is located).